# Is it possible to use google colab's GPU and my computer's GPU at the same time for training?

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, distributed-training

I wanted to train a big deep learning model like stable-diffusion. I wanted to know if it is possible to use PyTorch distributed to train my model simultaneously on both Google Colab and my local machine and utilize the power of GPUs on Google Colab and my local machine at the same time. What are the next steps?